# lines horizontal or/and vertical but never in other directions of line connectors block diagram with dot

Tags: dot2tex, dot2texi

This example is from

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922960/block-diagram-layout-with-dot-graphviz

How can I get connection lines that are only horizontal or/and vertical but never in other directions. Like the example of the opener of the thema in the link.

```
digraph G {
    graph [rankdir = LR];

    node[shape=record];
    Bar[label="{ \"Bar\"|{<p1>pin 1|<p2>     2|<p3>     3|<p4>     4|<p5>     5} }"];
    Foo[label="{ {<data0>data0|<data1>data1|<data2>data2|<data3>data3|<data4>data4}|\"Foo\" |{<out0>out0|<out1>out1|<out2>out2|<GND>gnd|<ex0>ex0|<hi>hi|<lo>lo} }"];

    Bew[label="{ {<clk>clk|<syn>syn|<mux0>mux0|<mux1>mux1|<signal>signal}|\"Bew\" |{<out0>out0|<out1>out1|<out2>out2} }"];
    Bar:p1 -> Foo:data0;
    Bar:p2 -> Foo:data1;
    Bar:p3 -> Foo:data2;
    Bar:p4 -> Foo:data3;
    Bar:p5 -> Foo:data4;

    Foo:out0 -> Bew:mux0;
    Foo:out1 -> Bew:mux1;
    Bew:clk -> Foo:ex0;

    Gate[label="{ {<a>a|<b>b}|OR|{<ab>a\|b} }"];

    Foo:hi -> Gate:a;
    Foo:lo -> Gate:b;
    Gate:ab -> Bew:signal;
}
```

Cross Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47501442/lines-horizontal-or-and-vertical-but-never-in-other-directions-of-line-connector

Because of special wish of someone who ask about anything to do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dot2texi}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{dot2tex}[neato,mathmode]
  digraph G {
    graph [rankdir = LR];

    node[shape=record];
    Bar[label="{ \"Bar\"|{<p1>pin 1|<p2>     2|<p3>     3|<p4>     4|<p5>     5} }"];
    Foo[label="{ {<data0>data0|<data1>data1|<data2>data2|<data3>data3|<data4>data4}|\"Foo\" |{<out0>out0|<out1>out1|<out2>out2|<GND>gnd|<ex0>ex0|<hi>hi|<lo>lo} }"];

    Bew[label="{ {<clk>clk|<syn>syn|<mux0>mux0|<mux1>mux1|<signal>signal}|\"Bew\" |{<out0>out0|<out1>out1|<out2>out2} }"];
    Bar:p1 -> Foo:data0;
    Bar:p2 -> Foo:data1;
    Bar:p3 -> Foo:data2;
    Bar:p4 -> Foo:data3;
    Bar:p5 -> Foo:data4;

    Foo:out0 -> Bew:mux0;
    Foo:out1 -> Bew:mux1;
    Bew:clk -> Foo:ex0;

    Gate[label="{ {<a>a|<b>b}|OR|{<ab>a\|b} }"];

    Foo:hi -> Gate:a;
    Foo:lo -> Gate:b;
    Gate:ab -> Bew:signal;
}
\end{dot2tex}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes cfr. The Diagram will be shown in a pdf compiled with LaTeX. The dot code will be transfered with dot2tex, a package to LaTeX. So the question has 100% to do with LaTeX. Also because dot2tex is not 100% compatible to usual dot code. I am glad to help you cfr.

Comment: "That doesn't really follow. You haven't posted the .tex file you convert it to." I do not convert to a tex-file. The dot-code will be in the tex-file. Please look at dot2tex for additional informations. I am glad to help you cfr.

Comment: "(Why else the cross-post, after all?)" Why not?

Comment: OK. So now you have an MWE - good. I suggest tidying up the comments to eliminate clutter.Asking for something we can compile is not a 'special wish' of mine. It is a standard request and should have been in your original question. But I had better refrain from anything further here, I think. I will merely say that setting out to irritate somebody trying to help you improve your question is not necessarily the wisest cause, even - or especially - if you think the person an idiot. What you want is straightforward, though - even for an idiot like me. Your code doesn't compile here.